# Centos sudo yum update fails

Tags: sqlite, centos, sudo, yum

I have the following error when trying to update yum for security can someone advise a fix, i have run yum clean metadata and that didnt work i am worried about running yum clean all as this was suggested as a fix in another post as i am not sure what it does?

```
    sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
centos                                                   | 3.7 kB     00:00     
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  23 kB     00:00     
epel/x86_64                                              | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                   | 736 kB     00:00     
epel/x86_64/primary_db                                   | 5.9 MB     00:00     
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/rpmforge/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
rpmforge                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
4028 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.10.46-1.40.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package aws-cli.noarch 0:1.10.56-1.41.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package compat-libtiff3.x86_64 0:3.9.4-10.13.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package compat-libtiff3.x86_64 0:3.9.4-18.14.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.58.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package curl.x86_64 0:7.40.0-8.59.amzn1 will be an update
---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-336.28.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package dracut.noarch 0:004-409.31.amzn1 will be an update
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share "ls /etc/yum.repos.d/" output? One of your repository is not valid which includes apt.sw.be url. You should disable that repo or delete repo file.

Comment: Hi @AliOkanYüksel thanks for the reply i am using a AWS EC2 the output is. amzn-main.repo     centos.repo        mirrors-rpmforge
amzn-nosrc.repo    dag.repo           mirrors-rpmforge-extras
amzn-preview.repo  epel.repo          mirrors-rpmforge-testing
amzn-updates.repo  epel-testing.repo  rpmforge.repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete invalid repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory.

First detect repo file with:

```
# grep -l apt.sw.be /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

Delete invalid repo file and clean yum cache with:

```
# sudo yum clean all
```

Comment: Sorry to be overly paranoid thanks for the answer but will sudo yum clean all affect anything with my setup?

Comment: No, it doesn't affect anything about your setup

Answer (score 0):

Although AliOkan provided a valid answer, here is the reason why it fails in the first place, as I've hit the similar issue as well.

As from your trace (you actually had a ref to el5 btw, which is not maintained anymore):

```
http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el[5|6]/en/x86_64/dag/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

This error points to some issue with RPMForge repo, then on the [official repo](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) there's this info:

> **RPMforge/RepoForge status**
>
> RPMForge/RepoForge is a dead project. It is not maintained. **DO NOT
>   USE**.
>
> See also https://github.com/repoforge/rpms/issues/375

It's not officially maintained anymore, but if needed, there are mirrors in place, see git issue above.